# Выделение частовызываемой функции в DLL

Tags: windows, функции, c++, dll

Целесообразно ли выделить функция в dll, если функция будет вызываться раз в 0,5 секунд? Вообще, какие операции должна выполнить ось чтобы выполнить ф-ию из dll?

Comment: Как правило, однократное связывание (подгрузка страницы из исполняемого файла или dll не зависит от того, в каком бинарнике она находится)

А достоинства dll другие -- уменьшение размера исполняемых файлов, возможность обновления функций в dll без пересборки исполняемых файлов и т.д.

Comment: Целесообразно. Я бы выделял функцию в DLL в нескольких случаях. Первое - она общая для нескольких ваших проектов, т.е. разделяемая. Второй вариант - это функция какого-либо модуля или плугина, т.е. в принципе она опциональная (может быть, а может и не быть).

Comment: ок, @alexlz, т.е. при динамичeском подключении код dll объединяется с основынм кодом, т.е. как если бы ф-ия была прописана внутри самой программы, я правильно понял?

Comment: да, @gecube, я как раз хотел использовать dll как плагин к программе.

Comment: @ололо В принципе можно наверное сказать и так, но на экзамене это было бы максимум "3". Происходит настройка адресов вызывающей программы для передачи управления вызываемой функции и отображение некоторой области адресного пространства процесса на код этой dll (грубо говоря)

В windows ещё возможна такая хохма, как смена адресов dll (явление, к счастью, весьма редкое, но будоражащее всю систему)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DLL целесообразно применять там, где один и тот же код может использоваться повторно. Также в динамические библиотеки засовывают ресурсоемкие функции, например, функции обработки различного рода хуков( на мышь, на клавиатуру и т.д ). DLL создавались Microsoft как раз с целью экономии памяти, как на жестком диске, так и в оперативной памяти. DLL - очень удобный механизм, позволяющий использовать какую-то одну функцию, не подгружая, функции другого типа и выгружать библиотеки из памяти по мере необходимости.